# Object segmentation not working for black object

Tags: opencv, image-segmentation

I am working on a Python script for object segmentation, using opencv. On some objects, this script already works fine. See for example the image below.

[image]

However, my script seems to fail on dark coloured objects:

[image]

I don't know why this is since I am pretty new to computer vision. My script for object segmentation looks like this:

```
import cv2
import imutils

image = cv2.imread(input)
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(image, None, 10, 10, 7, 21)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
retval, thresholded = cv2.threshold(s, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
medianFiltered = cv2.medianBlur(thresholded, 5)
cnts = cv2.findContours(medianFiltered,
                        cv2.RETR_TREE,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
```

Any suggestions on how I can improve this?

Comment: well, if you think about it... in HSV colorspace the color black is basically when the V channel is close to 0 (doesn't matter the other two channels much)... and you threshold and use the saturation channel which in this case may be quite low. For filtering black over very light backgrounds, maybe it is easier to threshold a greyscale image? however in that case, maybe the line under the door may be an issue

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have experimented with filtering a grayscale version of the image a bit. However, the difficulty here was finding a good threshold such that the yellow object would be detected.